# PDF in iframe glitch

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am creating a print interface, in which a print URL can be specified. It works OK with web pages, but this is what happened with a PDF:

[image: This is what happened…]

What have I done wrong? Here is my code:

```
function regPrint(url) {
    var printPopup = window.open("", document.title, "width=640, height=360");
    printPopup.document.open();
    printPopup.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>body {scrolling:no;}; iframe {position:absolute; z-index:1; top:0px; left:0px;};</style><script>window.onload = function () { window.print(); window.close(); }</script></head><body><iframe frameborder='0' width='100%' height='100%' src='"+url+"'></iframe></body></html>");
    printPopup.document.close();
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the PDF?

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle? might make it easier to help?

Comment: give your iframe a size (width and height). You defined the size of the popup, but not the size of the iframe.  If you set the height to be close to the height of the popup, it should fill the entire space.

Comment: @DannyGibas There's `<iframe frameborder='0' width='100%' height='100%' src='"+url+"'>`, looks like the size is defined?

Comment: I would try px based sizing when using iframes instead of percentages - especially for height. iframes are wonky when it comes to sizing - as in percentage based height does not work on them. I think VH might work if he wants it flexible.

Comment: [http://jsbin.com/dawupadajo](http://jsbin.com/dawupadajo)